# Why isn't this Javascript calculator working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, mysqli

basically I have this form which has its field populated by php and mysql. i am trying to get a javascript calculation I am using to work based on the zone they select and the quantity. But for some reason it is not working. My code is below. Any ideas as to why?

This is my Javascript code

```
        function getQuote() {
            var quantity = document.getElementByName("qty").value;
            var zoneSeat = document.getElementByName("zone").value;
            var quote;
            if (zoneSeat == "balcony") {
                quote= quantity*27;
            }
            else if (zoneSeat == "box 1" || "box 2") {
                quote= quantity*75;
            }
            else if (zoneSeat == "box 3" || "box 4") {
                quote= quantity*60;
            }

            else if (zoneSeat == "front stalls") {
                quote= quantity*22.50;
            }

            else  {
                quote = quantity*15;
            }
        }
    document.getElementById("quotation").value = quote;
}
```

This is my form

```
<form class="formDesign" action = "process.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>



                <p><label for="row">Row: </label><select name="row"></p>

                    <?php 
                        $strRow = "SELECT DISTINCT RowNumber FROM Seat";
                        $result = $con->query($strRow);
                    ?>
                    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_row()): ?>
                    <?php $i = $row[0]; ?>
                    <option><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                <?php 
                $i++;
                endwhile;?> 
                </select>


                    <p><label for="seat">Zone: </label><select name="zone"></p>

                    <?php 
                        $strZone = "SELECT * FROM Zone";
                        $result = $con->query($strZone);
                    ?>
                    <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_row()): ?>
                    <?php $i = $row[0];?>
                    <option><?php echo $i?></option>
                <?php 
                $i++;
                endwhile;?> 
                </select>

                <p><label for="numberOfTickets">Quantity: 
                </label><input type="number" name="qty" min="1" max="5"></p>
                <p><input class="mybutton" name="Quote" value="Calculate quote" onclick="getQuote();"></p>  
                <label>£:</label><input name="quotation" id="quotation" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="total cost"/>

                <p><input type="submit" name= "sub"></p>
        </fieldset>

    </form>



            <p><label for="row">Row: </label><select name="row"></p>

            <?php 
                $strRow = "SELECT DISTINCT RowNumber FROM Seat";
                $result = $con->query($strRow);
            ?>
            <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_row()): ?>
            <?php $i = $row[0]; ?>
            <option><?php echo $i; ?></option>
        <?php 
        $i++;
        endwhile;?> 
        </select>


            <p><label for="seat">Zone: </label><select name="zone"></p>

            <?php 
                $strZone = "SELECT * FROM Zone";
                $result = $con->query($strZone);
            ?>
            <?php while ($row = $result->fetch_row()): ?>
            <?php $i = $row[0];?>
            <option><?php echo $i?></option>
        <?php 
        $i++;
        endwhile;?> 
        </select>

        <p><label for="numberOfTickets">Quantity: 
        </label><input type="number" name="qty" min="1" max="5"></p>
        <p><input class="mybutton" name="Quote" value="Calculate quote" onclick="getQuote();"></p>  
        <label>£:</label><input name="quotation" id="quotation" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="total cost"/>

        <p><input type="submit" name= "sub"></p>
</fieldset>
```

This is what was inserted into the database in the zone table

```
insert into Zone values ('rear stalls', 1.00);
insert into Zone values ('front stalls', 1.50);
insert into Zone values ('balcony', 1.80);
insert into Zone values ('box 1', 5.00);
insert into Zone values ('box 2', 5.00);
insert into Zone values ('box 3', 4.00);
insert into Zone values ('box 4', 4.00);
```

This is the SQL statement

```
CREATE TABLE Zone(
 Name char(12) not null,
 PriceMultiplier float not null default 1.0, 
 PRIMARY KEY (Name)
);
```

Comment: What is it doing that indicates it's not working?

Comment: @Jonathan it isn't showing the result of the calculation.

Comment: I think one of your problems is that the variable `quote` is local to the function, but you're referring to it outside the function, where it is a different variable.

Comment: what is `$i++;` doing? and for what?

Comment: @NinaScholz it keeps printing the values of the items in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you may want to adjust your HTML for your onClick events

```
<input class="mybutton" name="Quote" value="Calculate quote" onclick="getQuote();">
```

change to:

```
<button type="button" class="mybutton" name="Quote" onclick="getQuote();">get quote</button>
```

now make some changes to your function

```
function getQuote() {
        var quantity = document.getElementsByName("qty")[0].value;
        var zoneSeat = document.getElementsByName("zone")[0].value;
        var quote;
        if (zoneSeat === "balcony") {
            quote= quantity*27;
        }
        else if (zoneSeat === "box 1" || zoneSeat === "box 2") {
            quote= quantity*75;
        }
        else if (zoneSeat === "box 3" || zoneSeat === "box 4") {
            quote= quantity*60;
        }

        else if (zoneSeat === "front stalls") {
            quote= quantity*22.50;
        }

        else  {
            quote = quantity*15;
        }
        console.log("values: ", quantity,zoneSeat,quote);
        document.getElementById("quotation").value = quote;
    }
```

The changes to the function that you should take note of are:

```
document.getElementsByName("qty")[0].value;
document.getElementsByName("zone")[0].value;
```

notice the plural after the word Element(s) and then the [0] which designates which element with that name you would like to access the value of.

next inside of your if and elseIf statements we changed

```
 if (zoneSeat == "balcony") {
            quote= quantity*27;
        }
        else if (zoneSeat == "box 1" || "box 2") {
            quote= quantity*75;
        }
        else if (zoneSeat == "box 3" || "box 4") {
            quote= quantity*60;
        }

        else if (zoneSeat == "front stalls") {
            quote= quantity*22.50;
        }
```

to:

```
 if (zoneSeat === "balcony") {
            quote= quantity*27;
        }
        else if (zoneSeat === "box 1" || zoneSeat === "box 2") {
            quote= quantity*75;
        }
        else if (zoneSeat === "box 3" || zoneSeat === "box 4") {
            quote= quantity*60;
        }
```

we changed all the double equals to all triple equal signs (check for exact match) and we need to explicitly check both sides of the or statment against the original variable.

Lastly, as Jonathan M pointed out we should but the re-assignment of the new value inside the getQuote function so it has the proper value.

```
 else  {
            quote = quantity*15;
        }
        console.log("values: ", quantity,zoneSeat,quote);
        document.getElementById("quotation").value = quote;
    }
```

Also notice I added a 
    console.log("values: ", quantity,zoneSeat,quote);

to the code.  This way, if you have the console open you should see that message once you click the "get quote" button.

Comment: if you console.log(quantity, zoneSeat ) right after you try and get the values, what prints out?

Comment: Hi @kyle nothing is outputted

Comment: Nothing at all? console.log("should be some data:",quantity, zoneSeat )

Comment: Ah ha, well it looks like we need to revisit the root issue - if you are not seeing anything in the console (you should at least see the "should be some data" part) then that means your function is never actually being executed.  There are a few issues now that I'm re-looking at it, let me see if I can update the answer.

Comment: sorry i got it to work, I just forgot to save the file and reload the page from the first booking page. Thank you very much!